# Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null

Tags: angular

I am trying to subscribe to the following method which reads data from a json file:

```
  getDefaultNavbarStyle(templateId): any {
    let template = null;
    switch (templateId) {
      case ActiveTemplates.Default:
        this.httpClient.get(this.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH).subscribe(response => {
          template = response;
        });
        break;
      case ActiveTemplates.Quick:
        this.httpClient.get(this.QUICK_TEMPLATE_PATH).subscribe(response => {
          template = response;
        });
        break;
      case ActiveTemplates.Front:
        this.httpClient.get(this.FRONT_TEMPLATE_PATH).subscribe(response => {
          template = response;
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return template;
  }
```

From another component:

```
this.defaultNavbarStyleSubscription = this.builderNavbarService.getDefaultNavbarStyle(this.navbarTemplate).subscribe(response => {
  if (response) {
    this.defaultNavbarStyle = response;
  }
});
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of null
```

What can I do to fix it? I've initialized template as null but set its value in the switch statement.

Comment: You can only subscribe to an `Observable` but your `case` returns a `Subscription` because you execute `.subscribe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having a method to make a request you are usually return the `Observable<any>` to subscribe to it as a caller:

Change it to:

Method:

```
getDefaultNavbarStyle(templateId): Observable<any> {
    switch (templateId) {
      case ActiveTemplates.Default:
        return this.httpClient.get(this.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH)
      case ActiveTemplates.Quick:
        return this.httpClient.get(this.QUICK_TEMPLATE_PATH)
      case ActiveTemplates.Front:
        return this.httpClient.get(this.FRONT_TEMPLATE_PATH)
    }
  }
```

Caller:

```
this.defaultNavbarStyleSubscription = this.builderNavbarService.getDefaultNavbarStyle(this.navbarTemplate).subscribe(response => { this.defaultNavbarStyle = response; });
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `template =` to each case and erase .subscribe

```
case ActiveTemplates.Default:
    return this.httpClient.get(this.DEFAULT_TEMPLATE_PATH);
case ActiveTemplates.Quick:
    return ...
```